# rEFIt defaulting to 32bit kernel

Tags: startup, kernel, efi

rEFIt is defaulting to the 32bit kernel of OS X which will not boot and will show this error message:

[image: Boot error]

at boot I have to press F2 then manually select the 64bit kernel.  How do I change the default kernel to load?

Answer (score 1):

At the OS X command line, try: `sudo nvram boot-args="arch=x86_64"`.

---

**EDIT:**

Try [resetting your NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) to get you back into OS X.  Since we added a value to the `boot-args` variable in NVRAM, resetting it will clear it out.

If/Once you get back into OS X, try the following [per Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3773):

```
sudo systemsetup -setkernelbootarchitecture x86_64
```

Rather than write into the NVRAM (which was likely modified by rEFIt), this writes a value to com.apple.Boot.plist and persists on the volume.

Comment: This didn't work.  It still fails to load the kernel at boot. - edit: now it won't boot either the 64 or 32

Comment: What do you see now?  Apple logo?  Error message?

Comment: I updated the question to include a picture.